# NativeScript open action extensions

Tags: nativescript

Is there way to open the iOS Action extensions from the NativeScript library?

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/extensions/sharing-and-actions/

Basically I'm trying to open a Text file, so I can upload it to iCloud, Dropbox or send it via Email. Basically like the "intent" on Android.

NativeScript implements a function called `utils.ios.openFile(this.documents.path + this.fileName)` but this is opening a new Windows with a share Button. When I press this button the action extension popup opens. Is it possible to open that popup straightaway?

A TypeScript/Angular solution would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this plugin. It will open the `sharing-and-actions` for iOS and on Android an `intent`.

https://github.com/braune-digital/nativescript-share-file